# Bumping the mole changing the picture but the mole not coming back

Tags: android, view, postdelayed

I made a game that you should bump the mole. I am using `postDelayed` to make the mole appear and disappear every few seconds.

The problem is that when I touch the the mole, it turns to the squeezed mole picture and the mole disappears (as it should), but when the mole comes back to the screen, it appears with the wrong picture (the squeezed one).

**STAGE View Class**

```java
private Runnable everyThreeSeconds = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        moleView.getMole().moveMole();
        isPop = !isPop;
        postDelayed(everyThreeSeconds, (3000))  ;     
    }
};


public AllViews(Context context) {
    super(context);
    test = new Paint();
    first = new First_Stage();
    isPop=false;
    post(everyThreeSeconds);

}

public void setViews(StageView mainView, MoleView moleView,
        PointsView pointsView, TimerView timerView,ClubView clubView)

{
    this.mainView = mainView;
    this.moleView = moleView;
    this.pointsView = pointsView;
    this.timerView = timerView;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    mainView.onDraw(canvas);
    pointsView.onDraw(canvas);
    timerView.onDraw(canvas);
    clubPic=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clubdown);
    canvas.drawBitmap(clubPic, this.x-39,this.y-20, null);

    if (isPop){
        moleView.onDraw(canvas);
    }           

     invalidate();

}
```

**Mole View Class**

```
public MoleView(Context context, Mole mole) {
    super(context);
    this.mole=mole;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (!bool){
        molePic=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nest_full_mole);
        canvas.drawBitmap(molePic, mole.getX(), mole.getY(), null);
    }else {
        molePic=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),     R.drawable.pow);
        canvas.drawBitmap(molePic, mole.getX(), mole.getY(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could I see the moveMole function?

Answer (score 0):

just added to the if condition an else that return the true back to false and it work

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
 super.onDraw(canvas);
 mainView.onDraw(canvas);
 pointsView.onDraw(canvas);
 timerView.onDraw(canvas);
 clubPic=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.clubdown);
 canvas.drawBitmap(clubPic, this.x-39,this.y-20, null);

 if (isPop){
    moleView.onDraw(canvas);
 }else{
        moleView.setBool(false);
    }           

  invalidate();
```